# Calculate number of working days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that runs at noon every day and looks for records entered between the previous day and today.

| CreatedDate | RecordIdent |
| --- | --- |
| 06/18/2022 | 123456 |

```
DECLARE @ReportDate = 6/21/2022
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(D,-1,@ReportDate) AND GETDATE()
```

It works fine for Tuesday through Saturday. Where I hit a brick wall is when the report runs on Mondays or the day after a holiday. I need a way to make the increment int of the `DATEADD` formula dynamic so that it changes to account for Sunday and/or a holiday.  *Note Saturdays are considered working days for us* So if today the report date is Tuesday 6/21 the increment int would be -3.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: the easiest way is to use a calendar table. If you don't have one, do a search on that and build one in your database.

Comment: Another vote for a calendar table. This is the way.

Comment: @Squirrel Good call. I actually do have a Calendar table that includes an IsHoliday column. My issue still remains where I dont know how to integrate that information.

Comment: Count(CalendarTableDate) where CalendarTableDate > StartDate and CalendarTableDate < EndDate and IsHoliday = 0 and IsWeekend = 0???

Comment: please accept the answer if it answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the 1 working day before `@ReportDate`

```
DATEADD(D,-1,@ReportDate)
```

It will be

```
SELECT MAX(CalDate) 
FROM   CALENDAR
WHERE  CalDate       < @ReportDate 
AND    IsHoliday     = 0  -- Not a holiday
AND    IsWorkingDay  = 1  -- is a working day
```

Incorporate into your query

```
DECLARE @ReportDate DATE = '2022-06-20' -- a Monday

SELECT *
FROM   SampleTable
WHERE  CreatedDate BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(CalDate) 
                            FROM   CALENDAR
                            WHERE  CalDate       < @ReportDate 
                            AND    IsHoliday     = 0
                            AND    IsWorkingDay  = 1)
                       AND GETDATE()
```